# "Iterate" and "iteration" as nouns

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, technical, mathematics

What are the differences between *iterate* and *iteration* as nouns?

I don't quite understand [the definition of *iterate* as noun](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/iterate):

> A quantity arrived at by iteration

For example, in computer programming, there are language features for iterations, such as for loop, while loop. Which one is correct: each *iterate* or each *iteration*?

I saw a lot of scientific literature use *each iterate*, such as [this one](http://pax.st.usm.edu/math/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture12.pdf):

> Since **each iterate** is contained within an interval ...

Comment: Has anybody ever ever ever seen the word "iterate" used as a noun? I don't mean in a dictionary: I mean, actually ever seen it used in a real-life programming book/article/presentation?

Comment: @Neil: I can't answer if *anybody* has seen the word used that way, but I can say that I haven't and I've been around computers for longer than I'm willing to say!

Comment: @Neil I have.  You can [google it](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=the+iterates), too, if you want.

Comment: I am (mostly) not a programmer, but in mathematics you can find *iterate* used as a noun.  (Pronounced differently than *iterate* used as a verb.)  I may say that sin(sin(sin(x))) is the *third iterate* of the function sin(x).

Comment: I have seen and heard it used as such many times.  It might be helpful to note that as a verb the pronunciation is what you probably know — like it-err-ate — whereas the noun is pronounced more like it-err-it.  This is much like the distinction between the pronunciations of "conjugate" as a verb or a noun (or adjective).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Each [iteration](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iteration)** is correct here.

*[Iterate](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=definition%20of%20%22iterate%22)* as a noun means the end result of many iterations.  So in an iterative function, each *iteration* is one loop of calculation, whereas the *iterate* is the sum of all iterations performed.

An important thing to note here is that *[iterate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iterate)* can also mean *a function that iterates*.  So if you ever see the noun *iterate* used, test both definitions to see which makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks! I saw a lot of scientific literature use each iterate, such as this one (http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGMQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpax.st.usm.edu%2Fmath%2Flambers%2Fmat460%2Ffall09%2Flecture12.pdf&rct=j&q=%22each%20iterate%22&ei=dJNvTsuRMdO00AHy5LD2CQ&usg=AFQjCNGLllwvVQ6gVhVg4AxiV8vBEE3Arw&sig2=ecJdNw_YcbUrl9jjlHxixw&cad=rja):

    "Since each iterate is contained within an interval ..."

Comment: What does "a function that iterates" mean? I don't understand the example in Wikitionary either.

Comment: A function is a mathematical construct which turns the info you give it into the info you want.  When a function is *iterative*, it  performs a certain operation on the info, and then performs that operation again on the answer, and then performs it again, and again, until you tell it to stop.  Each of the separate calculations is called an *iteration*, and the answer at the end, when you tell the function to stop, is the *iterate*.  But the entire function is also called an *iterate*, too.  Both meanings are used.

Comment: The second paragraph of this answer is a little ambiguous, so I'll suggest a clarification.  An *iteration* is specifically the process — the actions happening during one loop of calculation.  But an *iterate* is not just the final result after all of those loops; rather, it is the result after any one of those loops.  As such, I think the first sentence of this answer is incorrect: *iterate* is the correct choice.

Answer (score 3):

In optimization, I think that it's common to use "iterate (noun)" to denote the variable vector at the current iteration. For example, when you try to minimize the function f(x) by iterative methods, you generate a sequence of *iterates* x_1,x_2,...,x_\infty that ideally converges to a minimum of f(x).

In this context, "iteration" is used to denote the full process of going from x_k to x_{k+1} and can include multiple calculations, evaluations, etc. The points x_k and x_{k+1} themselves are the *iterates*.

Example sentence: "For a problem having n variables, our algorithm has been proven to generate a sequence of iterates with the distance between the k-th iterate and the minimum x* bounded by |x_k - x* | < B*n/k, with B > 0 constant".

I've personally used "iterate" and "iteration" with this distinction many times in papers I've written, and other authors in my field appear to as well.

Answer (score 2):

As nouns, in many contexts, [iterate and iteration are synonymous](http://www.collinslanguage.com/results.aspx?context=3&reversed=False&action=define&homonym=-1&text=iterate).

The definition given by Wiktionary for [iterate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iterate) (noun) encompasses not just a quantity, but a mathematical concept:

> (*mathematics*) a function that iterates
> *f<sup>2</sup>(x<sub>0</sub>) is the second iterate of x<sub>0</sub> under f.*

([PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/Iterate) has a more detailed mathematical description; they show the nouns *iterate* and *iteration* as synonyms for this idea.)

*Each iterate* refers to *each subsequent result of iteration* (x<sub>k+1</sub>,  in the paper you mentioned).

---

So, if *an iterate* is the result of iteration, what is an [iteration](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iteration)?

Wiktionary tells us that it can mean a single repetition, which is what makes the two nearly synonymous. This could be used in math, computer science, or indeed in art or music or writing, meaning:

> A variation of a design.

*Iteration* also means the act or use of repetition, and it has a domain-specific meaning you alluded to:

> (*computing*) the use of repetition in a computer program, especially in the form of a loop

So a computing *iteration* sounds a lot like a mathematical *iterate*, except that *iteration* is much more common; I'll certainly say:

> Hmm. It failed on the fourth iteration.
> The iteration in my *for* loop isn't working!

Answer (score 1):

An iterate can also be the state part way through an iteration.  For example, in an infinite iteration that converges, you can say that the iteration can be stopped when the distance between the iterates x_n and x_{n+1} drops below a chosen threshold.

Answer (score -2):

**Each iteration** is correct. **Iterate** is a verb, and **iteration** is a noun.

[Iterate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iterate)

[Iteration](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration?show=0&t=1315934267)

Comment: Apparently *iterate* pronounced "EYE-ter-itt" is a noun.

Comment: @drɱ65: the pronunciation as noun is same as verb. See http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=define%3a%20iterate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=euX&channel=fs&q=iterate&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=3JRvTtXAEMbJgQfzmp2NBQ&ved=0CB4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1fa7c254c97e187f&biw=1440&bih=641

Comment: You are right!  Hmm.  Well, my main point is still that there is a noun *iterate*, so the reasoning in the above answer is fallacious.

Comment: I'm really curious: when did you last see "iterate" used as a noun?

Comment: @Neil: 'iterate' sounds wrong to me as a noun, and of many online sources, only dictionary.com shows it as a noun. But it -is- used commonly enough in the technical language of math/CS to refer to one item in a sequence.

Comment: I suspect the dictionaries may be wrong. The mathematicians I know pronounce the noun closer to *iterative* without the final syllable, so perhaps [/ˈɪtərət/] while the verb is more like *iteration* without its ending